# accessing data in GET account/verify_credentials in twitter with php

Tags: php, json, twitter, twitter-oauth

When I use the method in the twitter API

```
$content =  $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
```

it returns a json that has all the data of the user

I know that I can access for example the Screen Name like this :

```
$content->screen_name
```

but how can I access Country and Country Code ...

Comment: do a var_dump of `$content` and look at his content, should be there ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the users' location with the `location` field. You will have to guess the country (and its code) from this.

For further documentation, see the corresponding Twitter Developers page : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/users.